# Google Analytics: Real Time Reporting API and Filtering by Custom Dimension

Tags: google-analytics

Any ideas how i would filter the response based on a custom dimension when making an api call to the real time reporting api?

Below is what i have tried setting the filter to in the api call, my custom dimension is called dimension1.

```
filters=rt:dimension1==test
filters=ga:dimension1==test
```

Both the above filter do not work for the real time api.

But it seems i can use the following filter when doing an api call to the Core Reporting Api

```
filters=ga:dimension1==test
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the real time api supports [dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/).

Comment: Or you might only be able to filter on goals and event.s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like the real time API doesn't support custom dimensions

List of supported dimensions and metrics below for the real time api.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `filters=rt:dimension1==test` as long as you are putting the dimension in your call. I'm not sure how you are making the call to the API. I'm using the javascript library and sending in JSON like this:

```
 'params': {'ids': 'ga:xxxxxx', 'metrics': 'rt:totalEvents', 'dimensions': [ 'rt:eventCategory', 'rt:eventAction', 'rt:eventLabel', 'rt:minutesAgo'], 'filters': 'rt:eventLabel==Submit', 'fields': 'rows' }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are not using any custom dimensions in your code example.